# how do i find out how much free space is in an array in c?

Tags: arrays, c

I typically use

```
int length = sizeof(array)/sizeof(dataType)
```

but this only gives me its size.

how do I check how much free space I have?

the only way I have come up with is whenever an array is created to give each element a specific value which indicates empty is there a better way of doing it ?

Comment: Define "free space". The sequence size is fixed. If you're storing items of *relevance* within this sequence, but not using all slots, *you* have to maintain that information in some additional counter(s) and/or using values the dictate "free". The language won't do it for you.

Comment: You have to code this yourself in C, for example by using sentinel values (as you suggest), or using a counter. C isn't a modern high-level language ;(

Comment: @WhozCraig yes free space as in data that's not relevant

so i need to make like a varriable and increment or decrement it every time i change the array

Comment: All items in an array are at your disposal. What you consider `free space` is implementation defined. The compiler or language doesn't know what is or is not `relevant` as this applies only to the problem you are trying to solve.

Comment: Yeah, that's easy - none.

Answer (score 0):

Just introduce an *arrayCount* variable which keeps track of how many elements you have in *array*. The number of free slots is then *length* - *arrayCount*.